# how to set the bold in part of the text in UILabel

Tags: iphone, label, bold

I am new in iPhone application development. How to set the bold in part of the text in `UILabel`.

Example:

**Step 1-** Separate all parts of the plant (stem, roots, leaves, flower etc..)

**Step 2-** Only test one part at a time

I need like example in `UILabel`

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/

Answer (score 1):

Implement  [`TTTAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/) or [`OHAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/) and use:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *theText = theLabel.text;
[theText applyFontTraits:NSBoldFontMask range:NSMakeRange(0,[text length])];
theLabel.text = theText;
```

to bold specific parts of the string (change the `NSRange` as required).

Answer (score 0):

For now, you're going to have to use a third party component, since there's no attributed string support in UILabel.

Try https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/

In order of increasing complexity, here's some other solutions:

Alternatively, use a WebView with HTML.

Alternatively, use a CATextLayer, this is only slightly more work than adding a UILabel, but you need a little understanding of how layers work vs. views.

Alternatively, draw your strings yourself using CoreText.